# How do I encode integers into BigEndian in Q#?

Tags: programming, q#

https://export.arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1908/1908.07943.pdf
page 4 point 1 states that we use the bits of an integer as a basis in our space. I understand that BigEndian grabs our largest bit and creates a qubit. I am wondering if there is a function within Q# that does this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a single function, but here's how you can do this with several library functions:

```
open Microsoft.Quantum.Arrays;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;

operation Demo () : Unit {
    let N = 12;
    Message($"Number: {N}");
    let bitsLE = IntAsBoolArray(N, 4);
    Message($"Bits in little endian: {bitsLE}");
    let bitsBE = Reversed(bitsLE);
    Message($"Bits in big endian: {bitsBE}");
    using (qs = Qubit[N]) {
        ApplyPauliFromBitString(PauliX, true, bitsBE, qs);
        DumpMachine();
        ResetAll(qs);
    }
}
```

- [IntAsBoolArray](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.convert.intasboolarray) converts an integer to a bit string with the given number of bits (in this case `[False,False,True,True]`).
- [Reversed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.arrays.reversed) returns the bits of the array in reverse order, i.e., converts them from little endian to big endian (`[True,True,False,False]`).
- [ApplyPauliFromBitString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.canon.applypaulifrombitstring) applies an X gate to each of the qubits that correspond to `true` elements of the `bitsBE` array ($|1100\rangle$).

Comment: what is the purpose of making sure that the true elements of bitsBE have an X gate applied?

Comment: Well, that's how you actually encode the state :-) Freshly allocated qubits start in the |0⟩ state, so to convert them to |1⟩ in positions which correspond to 1s in the binary notation, you apply X gate to those positions

Comment: Ok, I am looking to take one bit string and characterize it as qubit and do so for multiple bit strings in one quantum system. In that case, would this encoding produce redundant (non-basis) qubits?

Comment: This doesn't sound like the original question... Can you provide more details? An example maybe?

Comment: Sure! Thank you for being patient. "Each data value is represented by a binary string and is stored in an orthonormal basis state of |Ψ⟩,where |Ψ⟩is the initial state. Therefore, the data value lies in interval [0,2^(−1)],where n is the number of qubits." This is what I would like to accomplish. d is a data value coming from an unsorted database called D. All elements of D are unique integers.

Comment: This looks more like https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparearbitrarystate, though that one uses little endian.